# How do I exchange data using BLE in my app?

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have a application that I got froma freelancing team that uses classical Bluetooth in data exchange. I am in the process of switching it from classical Bluetooth to BLE.

Now there are different fragments each with their own viewmodels, viewmodel factories and their repositories that acts as an intermediary between the viewmodel and the DataStore class that hosts the data.

I was following a guide and what I achieved so far is scanning for BLE devices and connecting to them to display the characteristics and their properties (Readable, Writable, Indicatable, Notifiable). I have an activity that scans for devices and then upon selecting a device it goes to another activity, connects to the device and displays the characteristics.

Different Parameters are symbolized with codes likes these:

```
    enum class ReadRequestCodes(val value:String) {
    KEY_ADDRESS  ("08 00 00 00 20 30 05 11 00 00 00 00 00"),
    TOOL_ADDRESS ("08 00 00 00 20 30 05 27 00 00 00 00 00"),
    RPM_THRESHOLD("08 00 00 00 20 30 05 13 00 00 00 00 00"),
    BACKLASH     ("08 00 00 00 20 30 05 22 00 00 00 00 00"),

    POWER_SRC_TYPE     ("08 00 00 00 20 30 05 26 00 00 00 00 00"),
    BATTERY1_PERCENTAGE("08 00 00 00 20 30 11 00 00 00 00 00 00"),
    BATTERY2_PERCENTAGE("08 00 00 00 20 30 12 00 00 00 00 00 00"),

    HOME_POSITION     ("08 00 00 00 20 30 05 15 00 00 00 00 00"),
    BYPASS_POSITION   ("08 00 00 00 20 30 05 17 00 00 00 00 00"),
    HC_POSITION       ("08 00 00 00 20 30 05 19 00 00 00 00 00"),
    ISOLATION_POSITION("08 00 00 00 20 30 05 1B 00 00 00 00 00"),

    PRESSURE_SENSOR_GAIN("08 00 00 00 20 30 05 2B 00 00 00 00 00"),
    PRESSURE_SENSOR_OFFSET("08 00 00 00 20 30 05 2C 00 00 00 00 00"),
    PRESSURE_SENSOR_RANGE("08 00 00 00 20 30 05 2A 00 00 00 00 00"),
    PRESSURE_SENSOR_EXCITATION("08 00 00 00 20 30 05 29 00 00 00 00 00"),
    PRESSURE_SENSOR_SERIAL("08 00 00 00 20 30 05 2D 00 00 00 00 00"),
}
```

there are enums for read requests, write commands, read response.

Now in the fragments previously mentioned there are buttons that are supposed to initiate a request, basically you click and it requests the parameter that corresponds to one of the codes like in the snippet and acquires the value from the device I'm connected to. In other cases I type in data and send it to the device, and the parameter is symbolized with a code similar to the one in the snippet but for write commands.

Now the issue here is HOW to do I exchange data? The code below is form my call back function when I connect to a device:

```
 private val gattCallback = object : BluetoothGattCallback() {
    override fun onConnectionStateChange(gatt: BluetoothGatt, status: Int, newState: Int) {
        val deviceAddress = gatt.device.address

        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                Timber.w("onConnectionStateChange: connected to $deviceAddress")
                deviceGattMap[gatt.device] = gatt
                Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
                    gatt.discoverServices()
                }
            } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                Timber.e("onConnectionStateChange: disconnected from $deviceAddress")
                teardownConnection(gatt.device)
            }
        } else {
            Timber.e("onConnectionStateChange: status $status encountered for $deviceAddress!")
            if (pendingOperation is Connect) {
                signalEndOfOperation()
            }
            teardownConnection(gatt.device)
        }
    }

    override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt, status: Int) {
        with(gatt) {
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                Timber.w("Discovered ${services.size} services for ${device.address}.")
                printGattTable()
                requestMtu(device, GATT_MAX_MTU_SIZE)
                listeners.forEach { it.get()?.onConnectionSetupComplete?.invoke(this) }
            } else {
                Timber.e("Service discovery failed due to status $status")
                teardownConnection(gatt.device)
            }
        }

        if (pendingOperation is Connect) {
            signalEndOfOperation()
        }
    }

    override fun onMtuChanged(gatt: BluetoothGatt, mtu: Int, status: Int) {
        Timber.w("ATT MTU changed to $mtu, success: ${status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS}")
        listeners.forEach { it.get()?.onMtuChanged?.invoke(gatt.device, mtu) }

        if (pendingOperation is MtuRequest) {
            signalEndOfOperation()
        }
    }

    override fun onCharacteristicRead(
        gatt: BluetoothGatt,
        characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic,
        status: Int
    ) {
        with(characteristic) {
            when (status) {
                BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS -> {
                    Timber.i("Read characteristic $uuid | value: ${value.toHexString()}")
                    listeners.forEach {
                        it.get()?.onCharacteristicRead?.invoke(
                            gatt.device,
                            this
                        )
                    }
                }
                BluetoothGatt.GATT_READ_NOT_PERMITTED -> {
                    Timber.e("Read not permitted for $uuid!")
                }
                else -> {
                    Timber.e("Characteristic read failed for $uuid, error: $status")
                }
            }
        }

        if (pendingOperation is CharacteristicRead) {
            signalEndOfOperation()
        }
    }

    override fun onCharacteristicWrite(
        gatt: BluetoothGatt,
        characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic,
        status: Int
    ) {
        with(characteristic) {
            when (status) {
                BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS -> {
                    Timber.i("Wrote to characteristic $uuid | value: ${value.toHexString()}")
                    listeners.forEach {
                        it.get()?.onCharacteristicWrite?.invoke(
                            gatt.device,
                            this
                        )
                    }
                }
                BluetoothGatt.GATT_WRITE_NOT_PERMITTED -> {
                    Timber.e("Write not permitted for $uuid!")
                }
                else -> {
                    Timber.e("Characteristic write failed for $uuid, error: $status")
                }
            }
        }

        if (pendingOperation is CharacteristicWrite) {
            signalEndOfOperation()
        }
    }

    override fun onCharacteristicChanged(
        gatt: BluetoothGatt,
        characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic
    ) {
        with(characteristic) {
            Timber.i("Characteristic $uuid changed | value: ${value.toHexString()}")
            listeners.forEach { it.get()?.onCharacteristicChanged?.invoke(gatt.device, this) }
        }
    }

    override fun onDescriptorRead(
        gatt: BluetoothGatt,
        descriptor: BluetoothGattDescriptor,
        status: Int
    ) {
        with(descriptor) {
            when (status) {
                BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS -> {
                    Timber.i("Read descriptor $uuid | value: ${value.toHexString()}")
                    listeners.forEach { it.get()?.onDescriptorRead?.invoke(gatt.device, this) }
                }
                BluetoothGatt.GATT_READ_NOT_PERMITTED -> {
                    Timber.e("Read not permitted for $uuid!")
                }
                else -> {
                    Timber.e("Descriptor read failed for $uuid, error: $status")
                }
            }
        }

        if (pendingOperation is DescriptorRead) {
            signalEndOfOperation()
        }
    }

    override fun onDescriptorWrite(
        gatt: BluetoothGatt,
        descriptor: BluetoothGattDescriptor,
        status: Int
    ) {
        with(descriptor) {
            when (status) {
                BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS -> {
                    Timber.i("Wrote to descriptor $uuid | value: ${value.toHexString()}")

                    if (isCccd()) {
                        onCccdWrite(gatt, value, characteristic)
                    } else {
                        listeners.forEach {
                            it.get()?.onDescriptorWrite?.invoke(
                                gatt.device,
                                this
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
                BluetoothGatt.GATT_WRITE_NOT_PERMITTED -> {
                    Timber.e("Write not permitted for $uuid!")
                }
                else -> {
                    Timber.e("Descriptor write failed for $uuid, error: $status")
                }
            }
        }

        if (descriptor.isCccd() &&
            (pendingOperation is EnableNotifications || pendingOperation is DisableNotifications)
        ) {
            signalEndOfOperation()
        } else if (!descriptor.isCccd() && pendingOperation is DescriptorWrite) {
            signalEndOfOperation()
        }
    }

    private fun onCccdWrite(
        gatt: BluetoothGatt,
        value: ByteArray,
        characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic
    ) {
        val charUuid = characteristic.uuid
        val notificationsEnabled =
            value.contentEquals(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE) ||
                    value.contentEquals(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE)
        val notificationsDisabled =
            value.contentEquals(BluetoothGattDescriptor.DISABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE)

        when {
            notificationsEnabled -> {
                Timber.w("Notifications or indications ENABLED on $charUuid")
                listeners.forEach {
                    it.get()?.onNotificationsEnabled?.invoke(
                        gatt.device,
                        characteristic
                    )
                }
            }
            notificationsDisabled -> {
                Timber.w("Notifications or indications DISABLED on $charUuid")
                listeners.forEach {
                    it.get()?.onNotificationsDisabled?.invoke(
                        gatt.device,
                        characteristic
                    )
                }
            }
            else -> {
                Timber.e("Unexpected value ${value.toHexString()} on CCCD of $charUuid")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This was from the activity I displayed the characteristics in:

```
 private val connectionEventListener by lazy {
    ConnectionEventListener().apply {
        onDisconnect = {
            runOnUiThread {
                alert {
                    title = "Disconnected"
                    message = "Disconnected from device."
                    positiveButton("OK") { onBackPressed() }
                }.show()
            }
        }

        onCharacteristicRead = { _, characteristic ->
            Timber.i("Read from ${characteristic.uuid}: ${characteristic.value.toHexString()}")
        }

        onCharacteristicWrite = { _, characteristic ->
            Timber.i("Wrote to: ${characteristic.uuid}")

        }

        onMtuChanged = { _, mtu ->
            Timber.i("MTU updated to: $mtu")

        }

        onCharacteristicChanged = { _, characteristic ->
            Timber.i("Value changed on ${characteristic.uuid}: ${characteristic.value.toHexString()}")
        }

        onNotificationsEnabled = { _, characteristic ->
            Timber.i("Notify enabled on: ${characteristic.uuid}")
            notifyingCharacteristics.add(characteristic.uuid)
        }

        onNotificationsDisabled = { _, characteristic ->
            Timber.i("Notify disabled on: ${characteristic.uuid}")
            notifyingCharacteristics.remove(characteristic.uuid)
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know what else I need to post here but I can edit if the need arises. The point here I am stuck and don't know how to proceed. If I am able to connect to the BLE device and display its characteristics and all that, how do I get it to send me data or send to it data? How do I go from here?

Comment: With which device do you want to share data? Another phone? Why do you want to switch from Bluetooth Classic to BLE?

Comment: It's a component in a tool that uses BLE communication that the company I work for is using. The central device, is the phone with the app I am working on. So basically I either get data from the tool or send data to the tool as I stated in my question. 

Since the method of communication is BLE, then the classical Bluetooth in the app is not needed, which is why I'm making the conversion.

Comment: The tool already uses BLE or does your company still need to work on that?

Comment: The component that is used for BLE is ready that part is a component of the tool, so the component is functional. I need to communicate with it. The app is was used classical Bluetooth where as the component uses strictly BLE.

Comment: Ok, I understand. BLE works quite different from Bluetooth Classic where you had a serial connection. Please use a generic BLE scanner app such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile) to scan your BLE device for its services and characteristics. You might also want to ask the other team that developed the BLE device for documentation.  The following steps depend on the characteristics offered. Maybe the device offers one characteristic for reading and one for writing, maybe they used one characteristic for every data type

Comment: I was told I need to /write parameter to the component
   --> Build al Payload bytes for the command
   --> send the this payload to the BLE RX "writeCharacteristic" function
I have the UUID of the RX and TX which are for receiving and transmitting repsectively.

What I don't get is after connecting to the device. I have various fragments and those fragments have buttons that their action would lead to either requesting or sending data. The parameter is symbolized by the codes like in my 1st code snippet.

Comment: It seems like your problem is basically how to write to the device (and read from it) from your different fragments. If you wrap your BLE functionality in a service you can access it from other parts in your app. Take a look at [this example](https://github.com/googlearchive/android-BluetoothLeGatt/blob/master/Application/src/main/java/com/example/android/bluetoothlegatt/BluetoothLeService.java) on how to write such a service. I can also really recommend [this guide](https://medium.com/@martijn.van.welie/making-android-ble-work-part-1-a736dcd53b02) and its following parts